# Count number of instances which have a parameter in a list in common

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app to keep track of a school and I'm trying to figure out how many students each course has. The way my app is structured is like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    LEVELS = (
        ('A0', 'A0'),
        ('A1', 'A1'),
        ('B0', 'B0'),
        ('B1', 'B1'),
        ('C1', 'C1'),
        ('C2', 'C2'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LEVELS)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

So, the students in the API look something like this:

```
[
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Diego",
        "school": 2,
        "course": [8, 11]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Garry",
        "school": 2,
        "course": [4]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Dr Henrick",
        "school": 2,
        "course": [8]
    },
]
```

Now the question comes in my serializer, where I'd like to get a count for each course, ideally in a dict structure that would look something like this:

```
{ 8: 2, 11: 1, 4: 1}
```

What I've done consists of getting all of the students from the db and looping over their courses list, but I wonder if I could do something like that with Django's query system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) after you extract all of the course infomation.

```
from collections import Counter

students = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Diego",
        "school": 2,
        "course": [8]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Garry",
        "school": 2,
        "course": [1, 8]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Dr Henrick",
        "school": 2,
        "course": [8]
    },
]

print(dict(Counter([course for y in [x["course"] for x in students] for course in y])))
```

Output:

```
{8: 3, 1: 1}
```

Comment: what if a student is attending more than one course? e.g. `"course": [8, 2]`

Answer (score 2):

Django's querysets have an [annotate method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) for adding aggregations to results. [More examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset). In this case you want a queryset of Courses annotating a count of Students in the course.

```
from django.db.models import Count

courses = Course.objects.annotate(student_count=Count('students'))
```

This gives you a queryset of Course instances, each with a student_count attribute. If you really want to turn it into a dictionary of course.id: student_count, you can do:

```
{course.id: course.student_count for course in courses}
```